# Dual Boot Setup - Windows 7 Wont Load After Installing Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: dual-boot, 16.04, windows

I installed Ubuntu 16.04 side by side with Windows 7.  When I restart the computer, I do have a Windows 7 option in the grub menu.  But, when I select this option, I just see purple background screen of grub.  I don't hear windows 7 sounds (i.e. its not a graphics card issue).

I've spent the better part of 2 days trying all types of things based on these and other forums.  But I'm afraid I'm really going to brick the Windows 7 - if I haven't already.

Below is the output of boot repair.  I'm not sure what to make of it.  Hoping someone can help me out here.

http://paste2.org/Uz41wxhV

Comment: Can you able to login ubuntu?

Comment: Yes, Ubuntu loads fine.